# Resharper Quickfix for ?? order of operations

Tags: c#, resharper

I have a common problem where the order of operations is not respected when using the ? or ?? operators. In the following code, the programmer intended to set price to bigPrice + 5, defaulting bigPrice to 0 if it is null.

```
var price = bigPrice ?? 0 + 5;
```

Obviously the order of operations for the ?? operator evaluates the entire expression to the right as the argument, but it is a common mistake. Is it possible to alleviate this with a resharper quick fix / structural find and replace, essentially requiring parenthesis around your ?? statements? I've tried, but can't get a macro that identifies multi part arguments (0 + 5).

I'd like to know if this is possible / what the best way to do this is.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a `find and replace` in Visual Studio using regular expression,

In the find-replace dialog (Ctrl+H), enter the following,

Find what: `{:i:b??:b:z:b}{[+-/*]:b:z};` 
Replace with: `(\1) \2;` 
Look in: `Current project`

Initial code,

```
var price = bigPrice ?? 0 + 5;
```

After replacement,

```
var price = (bigPrice ?? 0 ) + 5;
```

A quick explaination of the find and replace expressions,

- Find Expression: `{:i:b??:b:z:b}{[+-/*]:b:z};` : `{xxx}` represents tagged expression i.e. it is a grouping of the expression found. `:z` stands for integer, `:b` stands for blank space, `:i` stands for identifier. `[xxx]` stands for any character in the set. And `\` is used to escape special characters. So in your case `tagExpression1` evaluates to `bigPrice ?? 0` while `tagExpression2` evaluates to `+ 5`.
- Replace expression: `(\1) \2;` : `\1` stands for first tag expression and `\2` stands for the second tag expression. The expression results in `(` `)` being placed around the first tag expression followed by a blank space and then the second tag expression.

[image: Visual studio find and replace]

Comment: I'm hoping for something a bit more systemic, as it may not always be a + sign, any operations before the semicolon should hopefully be caught.

Comment: @Superman, I have edited the answer to reflect the use of any operator (+, -, *, /) and statement termination (;).

Comment: Guys, out of curiosity, how Resharper factors into this solution?

Comment: @zespri, resharper has not been used in this solution. It is the `find and replace` feature of visual studio that is being used.

Comment: You might want to check out ReSharper's Structural Search & Replace, which lets you organize and apply your own structural alterations using simple Regex-like patterns.